# CFDocument not showing dynamic page numbers in lucee

Tags: cfml, lucee, cfdocument

Using Lucee, how can I add dynamic page numbers into a pdf file using the cfdocument scope variables?

- cfdocument.totalsectionpagecount
- cfdocument.currentsectionpagenumber
- cfdocument.currentpagenumber
- cfdocument.totalpagecount

I tried the code below. It generates the pdf, but the headers and footers are empty, instead of displaying page numbers, ie. "X of Y".

```
<cfdocument format="pdf">
    <cfdocumentitem type="header" evalatprint="true">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <strong><tr><td align="right"><cfoutput>#cfdocument.currentsectionpagenumber# of</strong>
                <strong>#cfdocument.totalsectionpagecount#</cfoutput></td></tr></strong>
        </table>
    </cfdocumentitem>
    <cfdocumentitem type="footer" evalatprint="true">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <strong><tr><td align="center"><cfoutput>#cfdocument.currentpagenumber# of</strong>
                <strong>#cfdocument.totalpagecount#</cfoutput></td></tr></strong>
        </table>
    </cfdocumentitem>
    <cfdocumentsection>
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <cfloop from=1 to=50 index="i">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna     aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis     aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint     occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<p>
        </cfloop>
    </cfdocumentsection>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: Please include your code example showing what you have tried.

Comment: There does seem to be a problem with `<cfdocumentsection>`. The header/footer and variables are output if you remove those tags.